# Auto NLP Entity Extraction

Tags: google-cloud-nl

I have trained model using Auto Natural Language Processing - Entity extraction. For now I have trained this model to extract single keyword under each entity from text however I want to tag single keyword under two entity to create a hierarchy. Example - For now keyword "Lazada" tagged under "Lazada_Ecommerce" however I want to tag this single keyword under two entities - sub-entity "Lazada" and main entity "Ecommerce". It would be great help if someone suggest if it is possible with Google Auto NLP-Entity Extraction model and how.

Thanks,
Satish Kumar
Data Scientist

Answer (score 0):

Google NLP Entity Extraction does not support entity hierarchies. The result of a prediction includes an array of entities, corresponding to each detected entity in the text.

https://cloud.google.com/automl/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.automl.v1#google.cloud.automl.v1.PredictResponse

includes property 'payload' which is an array of:

https://cloud.google.com/automl/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.automl.v1#google.cloud.automl.v1.AnnotationPayload

Note: If a "sub-entity" can only have one "main entity", then you could manage entity hierarchies external to the model, i.e., train the model to predict "Lazada" and other sub-entities, and externally identify that "Lazada" and others belong to a main "Ecommerce" category. However, if your entity model could have a "Lazada" entity underneath multiple main entities then your current solution would be appropriate (e.g., "Lazada_Ecommerce", "Lazada_SomeOtherMainEntity", etc.).